# CSS Lines Appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: the issue seems to only appear on OSX Mavericks w/ Latest Google Chrome (for me)

I have an event log that posts messages from the top down, and with every message, small black lines are appearing at the bottom right of each message and I can't figure out why.

Here is a working version of my game, click "Hunt for Blood" and when a few event log messages stack up, you'll see what I'm talking about.

http://codepen.io/RUJordan/pen/dcwLC

Here's a picture as well:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1AMR.png]

Here is my CSS relevant to the log div and msg div

```
.msg {
    float: left;
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
}
.column {
    padding:3px;
    float: left;
    width:30%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#222222;
} /* Hidden Elements */
.hp, .cycle, .gold, .log, .middleCol, 
.battle, .hiddenCounter {
    display:none;
}
```

And here is my HTML schema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Vampire's Hunt</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vamp.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="title">A Vampire's Hunt</h1>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="stats" class="column">
            <div>
                <h3 class="miniTitle">Stats</h3>
                <hr />
                <span id="spanCounter" class="hiddenCounter noRed">You have been dead for <span id="counter">0</span> hour<span id="singularHours" class="noRed"></span>..</span>
                <span id="spanInitMsg" class="spanInitMsg noRed">You are dead!</span>
            </div>
            <div id="divCycle" class="cycle">It is currently: <span id="cycle"></span></div>
            <div>Blood: <span id="blood">0</span></div>
            <div class="hp" id="hpDiv">HP: <span id="hp">20</span></div>
            <div class="gold" id="goldDiv">Gold: <span id="gold">0</span></div>
            <h3 class="miniTitle">Actions</h3>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div id="middleCol" class="column middleCol">
            <div id="shop" class="shop">
                <h4 class="miniTitle">A Dark Alleyway</h4>
                <hr />
                Herp Derp Derp
            </div>
            <div id="battle" class="battle">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="log" class="log column">
            <h3 class="miniTitle">Event Log</h3>
            <hr />
            <div id="msg" class="msg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script src="player.js"></script>
        <script src="element.js"></script>
        <script src="engine.js"></script>
        <script src="vampire.js"></script>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="https://github.com/RUJodan/js-vampire">Follow This Project on Github!</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do not think the JavaScript is the culprit, but just in case, here is the event log function, along with the functions it calls.

```
eventMsg : function(txt) {
    this.addBorder("log");
    this.showElement("log","block");
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    txt = "-"+txt+"<br />"+msg.innerHTML;
    msg.innerHTML = txt;
},
addBorder : function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.border = "1px solid black";
},
showElement : function(id,style) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = style;
},
```

This appears to work on FireFox and Safari, but not on Chrome.

Comment: Not reproducible on Firefox 28 nor Chromium 30.

Comment: Ah, apologies I'm testing on Chrome

Comment: Not reproducible on Chrome 31/Win 7 for me...

Comment: Do you need to run `addBorder` every time you add something to the log? The element style definition should work if you just keep it in there once.

Comment: I've tested it on chrome 31/w7 and was unable to reproduce that. what version of Chrome?, what OS? also check for plugins that might be interfering with Chrome's behavior.

Comment: Version 31.0.1650.57 Chrome, OSX Mavericks, no plugins, raw JavaScript.

Comment: Is your screenshot from the codepen link you provided? If not, there might be something you didn't include in the pen that is causing this...

Comment: @semmelbroesel don't worry about that, it's temporary. I haven't set a flag for single run yet.

Comment: @DrydenLong false, I get it in codepen and my local file. I did not exclude a single character in that pen.

Comment: I can see the problem with OS X Chrome.

Comment: @Juhana Ah ha! Now we're getting somewhere! :-)

Comment: So have you tried taking the `addBorder` out from the code? Does it still happen? FYI, I see the issue on Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m for Windows.

Comment: I can see the problem in windows Chrome. Its odd. It happens when i click the button but after I resize the display window they disappear

Comment: The addBorder function is not the issue. Play the game further, and when the Event Log div is moved right, the lines permanently go away.

Comment: However, Culyx managed to create a fixed version by taking out `addBorder` :-) Just saying...

Comment: And I'm just saying, it does not work for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-table` on div id "log". Note that it uses inline CSS that is reset on each click, so you'll have to overwrite this, otherwise it won't work.

**EDIT :**  `display: table` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

The lines seem to appear because you had `border-width: 0 0 1px 0;` instead of this:

```
hr:before {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Although, I have not tested on other browsers, but it seems to work with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m

fixed the line issue by changing:

```
eventMsg : function(txt) {
    this.addBorder("log");
    this.showElement("log","block");
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    txt = "-"+txt+"<br />"+msg.innerHTML;
    msg.innerHTML = txt;
},
addBorder : function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.border = "1px solid black";
},
showElement : function(id,style) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = style;
},
```

to:

```
eventMsg : function(txt) {
    this.showElement("log","block");
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    txt = "-"+txt+"<br />"+msg.innerHTML;
    msg.innerHTML = txt;
},
addBorder : function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.border = "1px solid black";
},
showElement : function(id,style) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = style;
},
```

Comment: I already said removing the `addBorder()` did not work in the comments, sorry.

Comment: I tested this change in codepen, and it did correctly remove the black lines with out having to move or 'refresh' the log; I should add my chrome has no plugins on windows 7

Comment: I know, I tested it as well and the problem persists on my end

Comment: Even if it doesn't work on your specific system it does seem related, wouldn't dismiss it entirely =D

Comment: I didn't, I discovered it was actually redundant, so there's that! lol

Answer (score 0):

Have another potential fix for you, change the css from:

```
.msg {
    float: left;
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
}
```

to

```
.msg {
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
}
```

Comment: yup tried this, it works, but it works by making the div use up all the space and hide/overlap the black lines.